Class with class variables as data attributes or using a dataclass
I am trying to decide between two styles, one using a class with only class variables and the other using dataclasses.
Class with class variables acting as data attributes:
class A1:
    foo: str = ""
    mut_list: list = []  # Note mutable default value

a = A1()
a.foo = "bar1"
a.mut_list = []
a.mut_list.append("baz1")

b = A1()
b.foo = "bar2"
b.mut_list = []  # Must set to empty list first before mutating
b.mut_list.append("baz2")

Versus making it a dataclass:
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class A2:
    foo: str = ""
    mut_list: list = field(default_factory=list)

c = A2()
c.foo = "bar3"
c.mut_list.append("baz3")

d = A2()
d.foo = "bar4"
d.mut_list.append("baz4")

Which way is preferred and/or more clear to read?

Do they actually have to be class variables, as opposed to instance variables, in option 1?

You don't have a "class with only class variables" here.  Since you assign values to both attributes, they become instance attributes, and the original class attribute values become irrelevant.

No, they do not necessarily have to be class variables as shown in option 1

In A1, you are defining unnecessary class attributes that are shadowed by explicitly defined instance attributes. You could have just written
# You could even omit the annotated names altogether; they
# are only used for type-checking.
class A1:
    foo: str
    mut_list: list

a = A1()
a.foo = "bar1"
a.mut_list = ["baz1"]

In A2, the dataclass uses the class attributes to automatically define various methods, one of which (__init__) you should be but aren't using to avoid having to define the instance attributes explicitly.
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class A2:
    foo: str = ""
    mut_list: list = field(default_factory=list)

c = A2("bar3", ["baz3"])

I would definitely prefer A2 over A1, but only because it makes use of an __init__ method. You could just as easily add an __init__ method to A1 yourself to avoid having to assign to a.foo and a.mut_list after A1() returns.

Thank you for pointing out that the class variables are being shadowed - I had no considered this before

Option 1 is obviously problematic, as you have to remember assign empty list each time, but that's because you are trying to use class variables in place of instance variables.
Here's how it should look with proper instance variables - from there a distinction of this vs dataclasses is a matter of preference and if you actually need dataclasses:
class A1:
    foo: str
    mut_list: list

    def __init__(self, foo = "", mut_list = None):
        if mut_list is None:
            mut_list = []
        self.foo = foo
        self.mut_list = mut_list

a = A1()
a.foo = "bar1"
a.mut_list.append("baz1")

b = A1()
b.foo = "bar2"
b.mut_list.append("baz2")
print(a.mut_list) # ['baz1']
print(b.mut_list) # ['baz2']


and then, seeing as this boileplate __init__ method is exactly what dataclasses where created to automate away, it seems like the obvious choice for the O.P. is to use dataclasses at once.
